# re rendering based on props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to re render when some prop changes ( prop change will trigger the sorting of data and the re-renders based on that data). I tried the below code but it does not work. It renders on initial state.  Also props, `props.sortingCriteria` ,are coming through properly  but when I change the props in UI it does not trigger re-render.

I searched and got this - https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes  . I think I am doing it wrong as I understand from that document. But I can not figure out how do I change my code so that it is in accordance with what is describer in the document . Here is the code that I tried

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import '../style.css'
import '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'


const CreateFlightCards = (props) => {
  const [card, setCard] = useState([]);
  const [cardLoaded, setCardLoaded] = useState(false);
 const [sortingCriteria, setSortingCriteria] = useState(props.sortingCriteria || 'default');

//initial state. this works as the code fetches data
useEffect(() => {   
  const fetchCardData = async () => {
      ...
     }
   if (!cardLoaded){
     fetchCardData()
       .then((flightCardsDataArray) => {
         setCard(flightCardsDataArray);
         setCardLoaded(true);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.error('Error occurred while fetching data:', error);
       });
     }
   }, [cardLoaded]);

 //trigger state change using props
useEffect(() => {       
     setSortingCriteria(props.sortingCriteria || 'default');
   }, [props.sortingCriteria]);
      
  // function to sort data
 const sortData = (data, criteria) => {
       ....
       return data;
     };
   // this also triggers     
   const sortedData = useMemo(() => {
    return sortData(card, sortingCriteria);
    }, [card, sortingCriteria]);

if (!cardLoaded) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

//render or re render
const columns = sortedData.map((item, index) => {
var depAirline;
.....
return <>{columns}</>;

}
export default CreateFlightCards;
```

And props (`sortingCriteria`) is coming from a different react code/file , which is like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const container = document.getElementById('range-wrapper'); // 
       ....
       ....           
        ReactDOM.render(
            <CreateFlightCards
              sortingCriteria={{ lowerRange, upperRange, sortBy}}
            />,
            document.getElementById('my-react-app')
          );
        console.log('After ReactDOM.render');
      }
    });
  }
});
export default CreateResultPageSortMenu;
```

How can I re-render based on props change in my scenario ?

**EDIT**
I did some troubleshooting and found that value of sortedData. just before this line `const columns = sortedData.map((item, index)..`. is an empty array for props change .

The below function, which is called from `sortedData` returns correctly for props change. I am expecting it to pass non empty array to `sortedData`, but  its not and hence no render for props change

```
// function to sort data
 const sortData = (data, criteria) => {
       ....
       return data;
     };
```

`sortedData` is fine for the initial state and hence I am seeing render for initial state

Can someone please help?

Comment: React automatically rerenders a component if any of its props change, so I don't know what you think should be happening, which is not happening?

Comment: It renders on initial state but when I change `props.sortingCriteria` , I am expecting it to sort the data  using `sortData` above and re render. The re rendering part is not happening

Comment: Try to log the `sortingCriteria` inside your useMemo function. That will indicate, if your memoization is causing the issue, as you can see when the cached value is updated.

Comment: It could also be something with the way you pass the sortingCriteria prop. It appears to be an object, and not just a primitive type? That might end up supplying an object reference, which I believe only triggers memoization based on reference and not value.

Comment: I did some troubleshooting and found that `sortedData` is empty for props change , please see my edit

Comment: Are you sure that `sortData` doesn't return an empty array?

Comment: Thanks. There was an issue in `sortData` , the code above is working now as expected